# SQL Server replace different characters in a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-update

I have a Barcode column with some data like below:

```
Z1B1S1A         -- Zone 1 Bay 1 Shelf 1A
Z10B10S10B      -- Zone 10 Bay 10 Shelf 10B
```

want to replace them with:

```
01-01-01A          -- I think I can get by with  1-1-1A
10-10-10B
```

The zone, bay, shelf can go from 1 to 99.

The problem for me is the inconsistent with 1 or 2 digit, and the last char 'B' can be mistaken for the Bay number.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'd like to use regexp_replace, but it's not available with MS SQL server. And thank you for fixing the format presentation.  Apparently, TRANSLATE is not avail for SQL EXPRESS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions. First solution is from help & idea of Analyst & DeepShiKha
1. First solution

```
-- SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
-- CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
select substring(Barcode,2,charindex('B',barcode)-2) AS Zoney,
       substring(Barcode,charindex('B',Barcode)+1, charindex('S',Barcode)-charindex('B',Barcode)-1) AS Bay,
       substring(Barcode,charindex('S',Barcode)+1,len(Barcode)) AS Shelf,

concat (
        substring(Barcode,2,charindex('B',barcode)-2),'-',
        substring(Barcode,charindex('B',Barcode)+1, charindex('S',Barcode)-charindex('B',Barcode)-1), '-',
       substring(Barcode,charindex('S',Barcode)+1,len(Barcode)) 
       ) AS ZBS

from TB_BarcodeTag4 
where  Barcode LIKE 'Z%B%S%'


2. Second solution is from my own

    UPDATE TB_BarcodeTag4
    SET Barcode = STUFF(Barcode, LEN(Barcode),1, '&')
    WHERE Barcode LIKE 'Z%B%S%' AND Barcode like '%B'

    UPDATE TB_BarcodeTag4
    SET Barcode = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Barcode, 'Z', ''),'B','-'),'S','-')
    WHERE Barcode LIKE 'Z%B%S%'

    UPDATE TB_BarcodeTag4
    SET Barcode = STUFF(Barcode, LEN(Barcode),1, 'B')
    WHERE Barcode LIKE 'Z%B%S%' AND Barcode like '%&'
```

Comment: what if a barcode is like 'Z23B4S56Z'..will have to write another update...??

Comment: moreover I strongly oppose the idea of formatting like this at database level..it should have been done at presentational layer ...

Comment: .it should have been done at presentational layer ... can you explanin further? Data need to be updated/replaced somehow, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

I am confident there is a much more beautiful way to do this but just wanted to give back to the forum that has given so much to me. Hope it helps.

This produces 4 columns.
1. Zone
2. Shelf
3. Bay
4. ZoneBayShelf (Last column is just a concatenation of previous three)

Used a combination of SUBSTR and LOCATE function to find the points at which to cut the BarCode.
CONCAT just to bring it altogether.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(BARCODE,2,LOCATE("Z",BARCODE, 1)) AS ZONE,
    SUBSTR(BARCODE,LOCATE("B",BARCODE, 1),
        LOCATE("B",BARCODE, 1)-LOCATE("Z",BARCODE, 1)) AS BAY,
    SUBSTR(BARCODE,LOCATE("S",BARCODE, 1),
        LEN(BARCODE)) AS SHELF,
    CONCAT( SUBSTR(BARCODE,2,LOCATE("Z",BARCODE, 1)),
            "-", SUBSTR(BARCODE,LOCATE("B",BARCODE, 1),
              LOCATE("B",BARCODE, 1)-LOCATE("Z",BARCODE, 1)).
            "-", SUBSTR(BARCODE,LOCATE("S",BARCODE, 1),
              LEN(BARCODE))
          ) AS ZoneShelfBay 
FROM DATABASE
```

Comment: There is a problem.  SUBSTR is not built-in function for MS SQL-SERVER. I replaced w/ SUBSTRING, but LOCATE is not support either

Comment: IF someone were to used Oracle SQL regexp_replace, wonder if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

It might look a bit messy but i think following code should help you:

First select the parts of string we are interested in:

```
declare @T1 table (barcode varchar(max))
insert into @T1 values('Z1B1S1A'),('Z10B10S10B'),('Z99B99S99C')

select substring(barcode,2,charindex('B',barcode)-2),
       substring(barcode,charindex('B',barcode)+1,
                 charindex('S',Barcode)-charindex('B',Barcode)-1),
       substring(barcode,charindex('S',barcode)+1,len(barcode))

from @T1
```

Now we can format as required:

```
select right('00'+ substring(barcode,2,charindex('B',barcode)-2),2)
       +'-'+
       right('00' + 
              substring(barcode,charindex('B',barcode)+1,
              charindex('S',Barcode)-charindex('B',Barcode)-1),2)
       +'-'+
       right('000' + 
              substring(barcode,charindex('S',barcode)+1,
              len(barcode)),3)
       from @T1
```

Comment: still not good, try this data  :  ('Z1B1S1A'),('Z10B10S10B'),('Z23B4S56C'),('Z23B44S6B')

Comment: try now..hope it helps!!